# Pentaho - ssh connect to remote server

Tags: windows, terminal, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am connecting via ssh to the server. Later, I'd like to execute something on that server, such as an "ls" or "cd" command. Is there any possibility to do this in Pentaho?

[image: 1]

I would like to be able to pass some command after logging in

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
With Pentaho, It is easy and simple.

You use "Run SSH commands" in Transfomer.

1, Declare connection to ssh server in General tab:
[image]

2, Put your command in Setting tab:
[image]